# Attaching action video.watches to publish action

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

I've created Create action in Open Graph App panel.
I also had View action and attaching this action worked fine,
now Facebook rejected View action and told me to use Watch which I am using now
but same code, and action is not attached to the explicitly shared 
all goes well, I get returned object FB.*callbacks.*_gcb31({"id":"10151457457579569"});

code is simple, am I using the right one for actions... I've tried video.watches and watch too

```
FB.api(
    '/me/friso-journey-cam:create', 
    'post',
    { other: 'http://getcu3er.com/projects/friso/action.php?id='+slideshow_id+"&sec_key="+slideshow_seckey, "message":message_to_send, "fb:explicitly_shared":true,actions:'video.watches', access_token:access_token,  }, 

    function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert("There was an error in saving the slideshow! ");
          closePopup();
       } else {
          slideshow.object_id = response.id;
          ////console.log("object created :"+slideshow.object_id)
         // onSlideshowFinish();
       }
    }
```

);

Comment: If you want to publish a video.watches action, then you have to publish it against `/me/video.watches`. And the parameter name for the video OG URL has to match the object associated with it as well, of course, and not be just `other` … that’s all explained in the docs, btw.

Comment: I do not want to publish video.watches actions, I want to publish action create, which works fine. I want to have also attached action Watch video or similar, which should actions parameter be used for. It worked when I had "View" unapproved action. For example I posted create action to my wall with explicit sharing, and you could see below the thumb, Like, Comment, View the video. Not it does not work with built in action Watch, and I was forced to use it by Facebook.

Comment: Ah OK, I misunderstood your question there. Do you have the _Linked Action_ configured correctly in your _create_ action’s settings in the app dashboard?